# Finding a replacement faucet spout

Tags: plumbing, faucet

I have a a faucet that leaks a bit from where the valves connect to the spout, and the threads where the aerator goes are badly worn. I was wondering if I can replace just the spout. It looks like screws in, so I should be able to, but I'm also not sure where I'd get a replacement. It's an old style (70+ years?), and I'm pretty sure it's an old faucet. Would most large home improvement stores carry a replacement, or would I need to confirm the thread size and special order it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are plumbing supply stores that specialize in old fixtures.  I would take a photo with scale for the distance between the pipes coming out of the wall, the size of those pipes, and the size of the nuts.  They would love to advise you.

Answer (score 5):

You might get away with unscrewing the spout, cleaning the threads on both the spout and faucet with a brass brush (just to clear any accumulated crud, especially if you have hard water), wrapping the threads with thread tape, then tightening it back on.

If that doesn't fix it, odds are good that you'd have to replace the whole faucet. I'm not sure where you're located, but that type of faucet isn't common at all in the US and wouldn't be available at a large home-improvement center type of store. You *might* be able to find something similar at an actual plumbing supply house. They may have something in a commercial line that would fit. If you go that route, either remove the faucet from the wall and bring it in with you, or take good pics with a measuring tape across the top of the plumbing stub-outs so they can help you find something with the right spacing.

Comment: commercial line, +1. *Chicago Faucet*.

Comment: I liked the brass brush idea. I did a first pass, but after looking closer, wow, the first thread is in really bad shape. I added a picture of where it starts. At one point, I looked for taps for faucet threads, but they use a non-standard pitch.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann you may consider using a triangular file. That will allow you to get into the threads and clean them up. It will take a very light touch and some care, but you should be able to clean them up that way.

Comment: I found out a little bit more. The aerator previously installed was a standard female aerator with 55/64"-27 threads. The faucet threads are a *little* smaller, maybe 13/16 or 7/8-20. I think the aerator was forced on about half a turn, and it "worked," but wrecked the threads. The threads where the spout attaches appear to be 1"-14 (or something very close). I couldn't even find adapters for the aerator.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that you may be able to find replacement for your wall mounted faucet spout. These are common in commercial or restaurant applications.

I found [this one](https://www.etundra.com/commercial-plumbing-supplies/faucet-parts/spouts/t-and-s-brass-062x-12-in-swing-nozzle/) but i do not know if the threads are compatible. If you live in  metropolitan area you could take it to a dedicated plumbing supply house and see if they can match it.

[More spouts](https://www.etundra.com/commercial-plumbing-supplies/faucet-parts/spouts/).

Comment: *T&S Brass*, +1. That was the other name I came across and then lost.

Comment: Did this style used to be really common in homes? I've seen it before in a 100-year-old home in the US, and there are similar ones when I do an image search for "old faucet styles."